# How do you reduce the space between pie chart and legend? (highcharts.js)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please see below example that comes from highchart official documents.
There is still some space between legend and chart. I want to make the chart as large as possible, but not overlap the legend.

The data of my chart is dynamic. The number of legend items is variable. Therefore I cannot use a fixed marginBottom/ marginTop, e.g.

```
chart: {
   marginBottom: 50, // does not work for me, as the number of legend items is varied.
   marginTop: -10
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8z6mqd6d/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the padding and margin on the legend to get back some space.

```
        legend : {
            margin: 0,
          padding: 0
        },
```

Depending on how close you want to get it, you can make margin a negative number if you need to.

http://jsfiddle.net/8z6mqd6d/1/